# Remove and before last author and correctly specify corresponding author for title and abstract

Tags: abstract, author, authblk

I use the following and I was wondering is it possible to get rid of the **and** between Author B and Author C, as well as properly assign the corresponding author. Currently it goes * a as I am using `thanks`, is there a way to specify the corresponding author correctly to a,*?

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\begin{document}

\author[a]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[a,b]{Author B}
\author[a]{Author C}
\affil[a]{University A}
\affil[b]{University B}

\date{}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
bunch of stuff
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please see if the answer suits the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```tex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand\Authands{, } % To remove "and"

\begin{document}

\title{}

\author[a]{Author A}
\renewcommand\Authsep{\thanks{A.A@university.edu}, } % To show "a*"
\author[a,b]{Author B}
\author[a]{Author C}
\affil[a]{University A}
\affil[b]{University B}

\date{}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
bunch of stuff
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand*{\Authsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Authand}{, }%<---------------remove and
\renewcommand*{\Authands}{, }
\renewcommand*{\Affilfont}{\normalsize}
%\renewcommand*{\Authfont}{\bfseries}    % make author names boldface    
\setlength{\affilsep}{2em}   % set the space between author and affiliation

\title{Aa Article Title}
\author[a]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[a,b]{Author B}
\author[a]{Author C}
\affil[a]{University A}
\affil[b]{University B}
\date{}    

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is an article.
\end{document}
```